# Function does not work properly in for loop - Python

Tags: python, string, function, python-2.7

I have a text file in the following format:

```
AAAAATTTTTT
AAATTTTTTGGG
TTTDDDCCVVVVV
```

I am trying to calculate the number of occurrences of a character in sequence at start and end of the line.

I have written the following function:

```
def getStartEnd(sequence):
    start = sequence[0]
    end = sequence[-1]
    startCount = 0
    endCount = 0

    for char in sequence:
        if char == start:
            startCount += 1
            if ( char != start):
                break

    for char in reversed(sequence):
        if char == end:
            endCount += 1
            if ( char != end):
                break

    return startCount, endCount
```

This function works independently on strings. For e.g.:

```
seq = "TTTDDDCCVVVVV"
a,b = getStartEnd(seq)
print a,b
```

But when I insert in a for loop, it gives the correct value only on the last line of the file.

```
file = open("Test.txt", 'r')

for line in file:
    a,b = getStartEnd(str(line))
    print a, b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because lines except the last line, contains newlines.

Try following (strip trailing spaces):

```
with open("Test.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        a, b = getStartEnd(line.rstrip())
        print a, b
```

BTW, `( char != end )` in the following code is always False. (same for the `( char != start)`)

```
for char in reversed(sequence):
    if char == end:
        endCount += 1
        if ( char != end): # always False because char == end
            break
```

Do you mean this?

```
for char in reversed(sequence):
    if char == end:
        endCount += 1
    else:
        break
```

How about using [`itertools.takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
import itertools

def getStartEnd(sequence):
    start = sequence[0]
    end = sequence[-1]
    start_count = sum(1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(lambda ch: ch == start, sequence))
    end_count = sum(1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(lambda ch: ch == end, reversed(sequence)))
    return start_count, end_count
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How about my code ? Is it an elegant way ?

Comment: I want to count the first char in sequence. For eg: AAAATTAGGAGGG, the starting letter A is occuring 4 times, and end letter G occuring 3 time in continuous order.

Answer (score 1):

Three things. First, in your function, you probably meant to `break` using the following structure.

```
for char in sequence:
    if char == start:
        startCount += 1
    else:
        break

for char in reversed(sequence):
    if char == end:
        endCount += 1
    else:
        break
```

Second, when you are looping through the lines in your file, you don't need to convert the lines to strings with the `str` function. They already are strings!

Third, the lines include newline characters which are like this: `'\n'` They are used to tell the computer when to end a line and start a new one. To get rid of them, you can use the `rstrip` method of string as follows:

```
file = open("Test.txt", 'r')

for line in file:
    a,b = getStartEnd(line.rstrip())
    print a, b
file.close()
```

Comment: Fourth, use [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-343-the-with-statement).